# Does the Microsoft .Net Test framework count the number Asserts invoked for a Test?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Does the .NET Test libraries count the number Asserts invoked during the invocation of a Test Method?

I'd like a report that says something like MyTestMethod1 -> 10 asserts invoked.

Comment: When an assertion fails the test run is aborted with the failed assertion as the reason. Tests do not continue after the first assertion is false so there cannot be an "assertion count" (as it's either 0 (Pass) or 1 (Fail)).

Comment: @Dai: He's asking about assertions that passed.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't.

However, console output will appear in test results, so if you create your own assertion framework that keeps track of this information, then a little code in your Setup and Teardown methods could cause the test report to contain a summary like this after a test passes.

Comment: A test really should have only one reason to fail, so if you have multiple assertions then it might be a sign that the test design is wrong.

Comment: While single asserts are ideal, they are not always practical when doing end-to-end tests. When you're manipulate target system into a specific state. It's helpful, to keep verify as you manipulate it. I find this extremely helpful, when determining if a regression occurred upstream or downstream of where I'm testing.

Comment: I agree with both of you. True unit tests should have relatively few assertions, but unit-testing frameworks are used for all kinds of tests, including end-to-end scenario tests, where you can get a lot more bang for your buck by simulating an entire user experience with multiple steps, and making assertions after each step. I'm still not sure of the value in seeing the number of assertions each test invoked, but I hate to just answer a question with a "no".